# How to pass and iterate over List<T> in a generic function

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, static-methods, system.reflection

First of all the purpose of this code is to reset static variables of a class when required i know its not an elegant solution but that's only what can be done for now at least .
Here's the code

```
public static void ResetStaticObjects<T>()
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    if (type != null)
    {
        var items = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            item.SetValue(type, null, null);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is how i am calling it right now

```
HelperClass.ResetStaticObjects<DemoClass>();
```

what i want is to pass a list instead of passing one class then call the same function on all of these classes

Comment: You cant write a generic function with N type parameters.
In that case you have to pass an `IEnumerable<Type>` to the function.  
`HelperClass.ResetStaticObjects(new [] { typeof(Type1), typeof(Type2), typeof(Type3)});`

Comment: You can't just set ValueTypes as NULL, you have to check each property is not a ValueType

Comment: When would `typeof(T)` be null? Is there any way `typeof` could possibly return null

Comment: @Flydog57 no it won't be null

Comment: Then get rid of the null check

Comment: @Flydog57 may i ask why is it bothering you so much?

Comment: @Learning - Please DO NOT add answers to your question. Please post an answer as an answer. This system is specifically looking for accepted answers as a way to be able to show that the question was answered. By putting in the question itself it will severely limit the number of people who will find the answer. Can you add an answer?

Comment: @Enigmativity sure thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the answer to the question i posted

```
public static void ResetStaticObjects<Type>(IEnumerable<Type>types)where Type:System.Type
{
     foreach(var item in types)
     {         
              var props = item.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
              foreach (var prop in props)
              {
                  prop.SetValue(item, null, null);
              }        
     }
}
```

and here's how we can call it

```
HelperClass.ResetStaticObjects(new[] { typeof(Class1), typeof(Class2)});
```